# Gridview con DropDownList ¿Como puedo hacer que la opción más seleccionada se muestre de otro color?

Tags: asp.net

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Me encuentro realizando un sistema, en el cual necesito que el DropDownList que está dentro de un gridview, al momento de desplegarse me muestre todas las opciones que estan en la BD, y que la opción que ha sido mayormente seleccionada anteriormente, se encuentre con otro color.

```html
protected void gvRequerimientos_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //Aqui cargo el dropDownList                   

       var dropdown = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("Lis_NuevoAsesor");
       if (dropdown.Text == "")
       {
          string Sql_query = " SELECT (U.nombre_completo +' '+ '('+CONVERT(Varchar(20),            
          COUNT(asesor_asignado)))+')' AS Nombre " +
          " FROM Requerimientos R right Join Users U on U.nombre_completo = R.asesor_asignado and  
          R.estado = 4" + " WHERE U.cargo = 1 AND U.estado = 'true' " +
          " GROUP BY u.nombre_completo ORDER BY U.nombre_completo Asc";
          
           SqlCommand sqlcomando = new SqlCommand(Sql_query, sql);
           SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcomando);
           DataSet dts = new DataSet();
           sda.Fill(dts);
           dropdown.DataSource = dts;
           dropdown.DataTextField = "Nombre";
           dropdown.DataValueField = "Nombre";
           dropdown.DataBind();

           dropdown.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Seleccionar Asesor--", "0"));

                        
           string ruc_asesor = Convert.ToString(((HyperLink)e.Row.Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text);
              if (ruc_asesor == "1500995506-K")
              {
                  dropdown.Items[2].Attributes.Add("style", "background-color:Blue;");
              }
}
```

Comment: Usada anteriormente donde? si es en tu bd podrías realizar un select count para verificar la opción mas utilizada y luego de cargar tus datos, pintar esa selección con ese id.

Comment: Lo, que sucede es que una vez que selecciono una opción, el resto de los dropdownlist pierde el color que le di.

Comment: ya pero aún no me dices donde se utilizo mas anteriormente, por que si está todo en la misma tabla y seleccionas uno y quedan igualados (la cantidad de selecciones) evidentemente no habrá color, no se si me explico @Claudio

Comment: El dropdownlist lo, cargo con la tabla usuarios, y tengo dos tablas mas, una que guardo los requerimientos y es la que cargo y la que ves en este momento y tengo otra tabla en la cual voy guardando los ruc y los usuarios cuando se asigna un requerimiento.